# Specific heat capacity at constant pressure for fully ionized hydrogen plasma

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics

How do we compare specific heat capacity at constant pressure of air to that of fully ionized hydrogen plasma? I was interested to know if Cp will be different inside sun rather than for dry air? Is there any formulation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the specific heat by counting degrees of freedom, per Clausius’s rule.  For a monatomic gas, ${{C}_{V}}=\tfrac{3}{2}R$ and ${{C}_{P}}=\tfrac{5}{2}R$; but for a diatomic gas, ${{C}_{V}}=\tfrac{5}{2}R$ and ${{C}_{P}}=\tfrac{7}{2}R$, because the molecule can also tumble about two axes.  (Caveat:  This rule presumes that the rotational degrees of freedom are fully *awake*, i.e., that the temperature is somewhat greater than the spacing of the first few energy levels.  Air is fully awake at room temperature.)  For diatomic nitrogen, ${{C}_{P}}$ is 7 cal/deg-mole or 0.25 cal/deg-gram.

When diatomic hydrogen dissociates and ionizes, each mole (2 grams) yields four moles of free particles.  Thus, ${{C}_{P}}$ increases from 3.5 cal/deg-gram to 10 cal/deg-gram.

Comment: are there any circumstances / experiments where people have measured a constant $\frac{12}{2}R$ heat capacity for a hydrogen plasma?

Comment: @creillyucla -- I don't know about experimental work. Where did you get 12/2, vice the theoretical value for free particles? Attractive interactions?  When you reference things to the gas constant, is that per mole of diatomic, monatomic, or electrons and protons?  I'm confused.

Comment: 1 mole of $\text{H}_2$ would give 4 moles of particles once fully dissociated and ionized. Each particle has 3 translational degrees of freedom so we have $3 \times 4 \times \frac{1}{2}R$ for the heat capacity at constant *volume*. That gives then $\left( \frac{12}{2} + 1 \right)R$ heat capacity at constant *pressure*. This would then be 7 cal/deg-gram for atomic or diatomic hydrogen right?

Comment: Nope.  It’s $4(\tfrac{3}{2}+1)R=20$ cal/deg/(2 grams).

Comment: Ahh ok I see my error. Thanks for the clarification. Still though I am wondering in what circumstances the heat capacity of a hydrogen plasma ever conforms to the 10 cal/deg/gram prediction. If the gas is dilute enough we can certainly ignore effects due to degeneracy though it is not clear to me when the long range Coulomb interactions can be neglected.

Comment: You could work up a quick ‘n dirty approximation to the Coulomb interaction energy from Debye screening theory.  I have no idea how accurate it would be.